# Add PARTUUID to DOS MBR

Tags: partition, fdisk, uuid, partition-table

I have an MBR style formatted SD card where I need a PARTUUID in order to mount a partition there as the rootfs (via linux kernel parameter `root=PARTUUID=...`).  Using an fs UUID does not work.

However, `blkid` does not show any PARTUUIDs, only UUIDs.

I understand that PARTUUID is not a historical feature of MBRs, but that they can still be used.  I have looked around for a way to add or change a PARTUUID, but all I can find is stuff where a GPT is being used.

I've seen various ways to extract an existing uuid but the identifier I get is always just four null bytes (i.e., all zeros).  This is also what `fdisk` gives as the "Disk Identifier", `0x00000000`.

Comment: BTW your "answer to a related question" link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

The PARTUUIDs used with MBR's are based on the "disk identifier", which evidently is not mandatory -- you can end up without one and the partition table is still functional.

> I've read this answer to a related question, but the identifier pulled that way is just four null bytes (i.e., all zeros).  This is also what `fdisk` gives as the "Disk Identifier", `0x00000000`.

If you use `fdisk` to change the identifier to a non-zero value, you will magically have PARTUUIDs reported afterwards.

1. This is an "expert" option; from the main menu choose `x`.
2. From the expert menu, choose `i`.
3. Enter any eight random hex digits, prefaced with `0x`, e.g., `Oxd3b587f`.
4. Go back to the main menu, `r`, and write the table, `w`.

`blkid` should now report `PARTUUID`s for the partitions.